# Is using namespace std; mandatory

Tags: c++

How come this piece of code doesn't need std namespace.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     printf("Hello World");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because stdio.h is a C header file that doesn't know anything about namespaces.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is never mandatory. In fact, you will do yourself a big favor [if you completely forget that this statement exists in C++, and never use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Possible helpful or related [Why using namespace std is necessary here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509668/why-using-namespace-std-is-necessary-here)

Answer (score 2):

Because you included a C header, not a C++ header.

> `[library.c/1]:` The C++ standard library also makes available the facilities of the C standard library, suitably adjusted to ensure static type safety.
>
> `[depr.c.headers.other/1]:` **Every C header** other than `<complex.h>`, `<iso646.h>`, `<stdalign.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, and `<tgmath.h>`, **each of which has a name of the form `<name.h>`, behaves as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the corresponding `<cname>` header is placed within the global namespace scope**, except for the functions described in `[sf.cmath]`, the declaration of `std::byte` (`[cstddef.syn]`), and the functions and function templates described in `[support.types.byteops]`. *[..]*  **It is unspecified whether these names are first declared or defined within namespace scope (`[basic.scope.namespace]`) of the namespace `std` and are then injected into the global namespace scope by explicit *using-declarations*** (`[namespace.udecl]`).

The last bolded part above says that you *may* have been able to use `std::printf` as well, but that there is no guarantee of that.

Also note that the header is deprecated:

> `[diff.mods.to.headers/1]:` For compatibility with the C standard library, the C++ standard library provides the C headers enumerated in `[depr.c.headers]`, but their use is deprecated in C++.

On the flip side of the coin, if you'd included `cstdio` instead, you'd be guaranteed to get `std::printf` but the availability of `::printf` (the fully-qualified name of the global symbol you used) would not be guaranteed:

> `[headers/4]:` Except as noted in `[library]` through `[thread]` and `[depr]`, **the contents of each header *cname* is the same as that of the corresponding header *name.h* as specified in the C standard library. In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope of the namespace `std`**. **It is unspecified whether these names** (including any overloads added in `[language.support]` through `[thread]` and `[depr]`) **are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace `std` by explicit *using-declarations*** (`[namespace.udecl]`).

---

Short version:

- C headers like `stdio.h` are in the global namespace, and possibly also in `std`;
- C++ headers like `cstdio` are in the namespace `std`, and possibly also in the global namespace.

You only need `using namespace std` or `std::` when you're using the namespace `std`,

Answer (score 1):

The stdio.h header file allows you to use additional methods in the standard library that do not exist in all C++ code by default.  By adding the line #include , you are instructing the compiler to copy the declarations in that header file into your code so you have access to them.

The line `using namespace std` allows you to utilize methods in the standard namespace without having to call out the standard name space each time.  This helps eliminate typos, but could introduce other errors (if two namespaces have the same method signature).
For example,

`#include <iostream>
std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;`

Could be written as:

`#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;`

Comment: _"The stdio.h header file does not use namespace"_ It might!

Answer (score 0):

`using namespace std` makes names from the standard namespace visible in your namespace.

`stdio.h` i a header that doesn't use its own namespace but instead puts its functions (e.g. printf) etc. in the namespace in which you include it (in your case the global namespace). Therefore you can access them directly.

Note that including headers in a namespace is not generally recommended (see first comment for an example), I only mentioned it for the sake of completeness since it might not be obvious for a beginner that the placement of the include makes a difference.

Comment: Note: I don't recommend including Library headers in other namespaces. It can get really ugly. https://ideone.com/jFyvO3 works. https://ideone.com/eaivgJ does not, and have fun untangling that mess of error messages.